# Visual Studio + PhoneGap 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova

I have a mobile project to do which is cross platform, and I decided finally to work with PhoneGap. After installing PhoneGap 2.0 in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I tried a simple example :

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello Cordova</h1>
    <div id="welcomeMsg"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('bonjour'); 
    </script>
</body>
```

The emulator (Windows Phone Emulator) doesn't display anything. I don't know if the problem is from the emulator or because PhoneGap didn't execute the javascript code.

Comment: Have you put the phonegap library into the head? Are you waiting for the deviceready event?